# Android - Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: java, android, mysql

In Logcat It Displays : Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

In Catch Block Message Box I am Having An Error Like `println` needs a `message`. Please Help Me.

I Use Android Studio 2.0

Here is LOGCAT :

> "12-13 03:48:40.598 2129-2129/com.mysqlapp.bug.mysqlapp
>   W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input
>   event receiver has already been disposed."

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etUserName,etPassword;
String userName,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

}
public void btnLoginClick(View v)
{
    try
    {
        userName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Hello","Here");
        MySqlDatabaseHelper sqlCls = new MySqlDatabaseHelper(this);
        sqlCls.doInBackground("login",userName,password);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Something Went Wrong");
        alert.setMessage("-"+ex.getMessage()+"-");
        alert.show();
    }

  }
}
```

Here is Second Class :

```
public class MySqlDatabaseHelper extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context ctx;
String method,userID,userName,password,postData,result;

MySqlDatabaseHelper(Context _ctx)
{
    ctx = _ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        method = params[0].toString();

        if(method.equals("login"))
        {

            userName = params[1].toString();
            password = params[2].toString();
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/Android/login.php");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            postData = URLEncoder.encode("uname","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

            bw.write(postData);

            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            osw.close();
            os.close();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }

            br.close();
            isr.close();
            is.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            return result;


        }
        else
        {
            return "NONE";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String err = (ex.getMessage() == null) ? "Error occured" : ex.getMessage();
        Log.e("Err",err);

        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alert.setTitle("Something Went Wrong1");
        alert.setMessage("-"+ex.getMessage()+"-");
        alert.show();
        return "ERR";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alert.setTitle("Successfully Worked");
    alert.setMessage("-"+result+"-");
    alert.show();
   }
}
```